# Realistic cost of pulse units for nuclear pulse propulsion?

Tags: propulsion, spacecraft, nuclear

Nuclear pulse propulsion https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Orion_(nuclear_propulsion) was believed to be - by it proponents - far superior to chemical propulsion. Either because max. delta v you can potentially achieve with NPP spacecraft in deep space or total payload that NPP spacecraft can place into orbit during launch from Earth.

From this article https://web.archive.org/web/20111109175529/http://www.astronautix.com/articles/probirth.htm quote " Does it make any sense to even think of reviving the nuclear-pulse concept? Economically the answer is yes. Pedersen (55) says that 10,000-ton spaceships with 10,000-ton payloads are feasible ". I didn't read all old books and studies from list of sources, but since not single NPP spacecraft was ever tested (even for suborbital flight), if NPP spacecrafts with payload of 10 000t to orbit are feasible could be only author subjective opinion.

More important is cost of pulse units that this NPP spacecraft will need. From most sources you will need about 350-1000 pulse units with strength about 5 kilotons, which is about one third of atomic bomb dropped on Hiroshima. Article above stated this about potential cost of pulse units " How much would the pulse units cost ? Pedersen gives this amazingly low figure of 10,000 to $40,000 for the early Martin design (56); there is the reason to think that 1 million is an upper limit. Freeman Dyson estimated 500,000 USD as reasonable per-unit cost with total fuel cost 175 million USD."

Are these cost estimates realistic ? From this article https://blog.ucsusa.org/elliott-negin/how-much-cost-to-create-nuclear-weapon/ even refurbish old submarine nuclear warhead to extend it lifetime cost about 2 million USD per unit and build new nuclear warheads (not counting delivery system) cost about 20 million USD per unit.

NPP Spacecraft pulse units can have much lower blast yield than most current US military warheads, but there are other factors which could make them more expansive. For example timing of the explosions must be extremely precise for safety of the spacecraft during entire launch. Pulse units must be designed for very little radioactive fallout even in case you launch from isolated island in south Pacific. And you should also try to limit EMP effects as much as possible to protect satellites in LEO.

Couldn't all this issues result in cost of NPP pulse units being same or higher, than cost of current US military warheads with much higher blast yield ?

Comment: My guess is that the equation isn't really dominated by the marginal cost per unit, but rather the multi-trillion cost of running a mass production nuclear warhead program.

Comment: Maybe, but can 5 kiloton nuclear warhead really have marginal cost under 1 million USD, especially if it must be designed like pulse unit with very little fallout, limited EMP effects and extremely precise explosion timing, all of which is not needed for standard nuclear warheads.

Comment: I wonder at what point you run out of uranium.